# Исчезают элементы после обновления страницы

Tags: jquery

Всем Привет, вопрос следующий: После входа в систему появляются новые менюшки, кнопки и т.д., но стоит обновить страницу все выходит на исходную (все что должно быть show() переходит в {display: none;} сss, причем сессия активна

```
function loginAjax(){
  $.post( "/login.php",
  {'username': $('#email').val(), 'password' : $('#password').val(), 'submit' :'',  },
  function( data ) { 
      if(data == 1){ 

          $("#err").html("Все ОК").show();
          $("#uLogin").slideUp('slow').show();
           $("#log").show();

          $("#loginModal").modal("hide");
          $(".row").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

При формировании страницы на сервере Вы должны анализировать активна сессия или нет и в зависимости от этого изначально делать объекты видимыми или нет.

Скажем ко всем объектам добавлять один из классов `logged`, `not-logged`, а на сервере писать как-то так

```
$class = (userIsLogged()) ? 'not-logged' : 'logged';
printf('<style>.%s {display: none}</style>', $class);
```

Второй способ - после загрузки страницы в JS проверять залогинен ли пользователь (аяксом или считывая какой-то признак со страницы) и менять видимость элементов

---

А вообще, элементов, которые видны залогиненному пользователю, на обычной странице быть вообще не должно. Даже скрытых.

Comment: Перерыл кучу всего, но как JS проверить что сессия активна или нет не нашел

Comment: @JoinJexon При чем здесь JS? _При формировании страницы **на сервере**_

Comment: Да, страница формируется и сессия активна, вопрос как это срастить с jqery

Comment: @JoinJexon Я же написал как. И даже код привел. Чего не хватает?

Comment: anton-shchyrov получается следующее: if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ 
printf ('<style>#topbar { display:block;}</style>');   }   ответ в консоли приходит но это все прописывается в обработчике php а главная страница на html и аяксом как я понял тут непоможешь

Comment: @JoinJexon `Второй способ - после загрузки страницы в JS проверять залогинен ли пользователь (аяксом или считывая какой-то признак со страницы) и менять видимость элементов`